# How are Linux work queues working?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm new to Linux device drivers writing and I'm trying to make a device driver that handles an UART chip. For this I decided to use work ques as my bottom half processing because I have to use some semaphores when handling the data that I get from the UART chip.
A work queue handler that was scheduled earlier in an interrupt now gets executed and during it's execution it will sleep at a semaphore. During this time the interrupt handler is called again and schedules the same work queue handler. Will the work queue handler be executed again before the first execution of it finishes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of work queues is to allow concurrent execution on different CPUs. There is a flag WQ_NON_REENTRANT that changes this behavior. More information can be found in this post http://lwn.net/Articles/403891/

But it seems that in recent kernels work queues are non-reentrant by default - see 
http://lwn.net/Articles/511190